# Condition on the sign of the dependent variable

Tags: regression, bias

I have a dataset on two series $X_{i,t}$ and $Y_{i,t}$. Plotting the average value of $Y_{i,t}$ defined as $\bar{Y_i}=\frac{1}{T} \displaystyle \sum_{t=1}^{T}{Y_{i,t}}$ against $\bar{X_i}$ clearly shows a U shape relationship with $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ being negatively correlated when $\bar{X_i}<0$ and conveversely.

I would like to test this in a linear model, and my goal is to keep it very simple if possible. So the first thing I did was to run the following:

$$
\bar{Y_i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{X_i}+ D_i \gamma + \varepsilon_{i},
$$
$D_i$ is a set of control variable.

And to run it for $\bar{Y_i}<0$ and for $\bar{Y_i}>0$ separately. This gives me exactly what I want, but I am pretty sure this violate the OLS condition to get unbias coefficient since there is clear selection bias. I have also allowed $\beta_1$ to vary with the sign of $\bar{Y_i}$ and run the regression on all observations but here again I think this makes the covariate being correlated with the error term.

I have tried looking for indirect predictor of the sign of $Y_{i}$ but did not find anything convincing.

Comment: If you have a U-shaped relation between any $X_i$ and the $Y_i$ , you should look at modelling non-linear associations. There are multiple ways of doing this: figuring out a suitable transformation of your data (using fractional polynomials), fitting (restricted) splines, and more. Using any of such adjustments to the 'regular' linear regression you should be able to model both the negative and positive parts of $Y_i$ in one model.

Comment: Thanks, I have a part where I use a non linear model. But I am sure the good model is piecewise linear with a cut at 0 and I would really like to keep it simple for various resons, do you know how to model this?

Comment: So you have a relationship which is exactly 'V-shaped' (not U-shaped, and nothing else)? Then you could transform the $X_i$ variable by centering the variable at the point where the lowest point is (name it $h$) and then taking the absolute value of this centred variable like so $abs(X_i - h)$. Using this transformed variable will result in a V-shape, but I strongly suggest you to obtain good argument to assume this linearity in order to support this transformation.

Answer (score 1):

(Notation note: I'm dropping the bar on $\bar{x}$ to reduce clutter.)

#### Polynomial curve fitting:

You could estimate a polynomial relationship between $y_i$ and $x_i$. When I hear $U$ shaped relationship, I think a [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola).

For example run the regression:

$$y_i = b_0 + b_1 x_i  + b_2 x^2_i + \epsilon_i$$

Especially if you're adding higher order terms, the numerical properties of a polynomial regression can be improved by standardizing. For example, let $\hat{\mu}$ be the estimated mean of $x_i$ and let $\hat{s}_x$ be the estimated standard deviation of $x_i$. Define $z_i$ as the standardized $x_i$.

$$ z_i = f(x_i) = \frac{x_i - \hat{\mu}_x}{s_x}$$

Then you could run the regression on $z$. If you went up to degree 3, it would be:

$$ y_i = c_0 + c_1 z_i + c_2 z_i^2 + c_3 z_i^3  + \epsilon_i$$

Then $\operatorname{E}[y \mid x] = c_0 + c_1 f(x) + c_2 f(x)^2 + c_3 f(x)^3$.

Fitting a polynomial to the conditional expectation function can capture more complicated functional forms. A limitation is that as the order of the polynomial increases, the terms increasingly become collinear. Fit a too high order polynomial and you'll overfit the data (if you can even numerically compute the OLS result).

#### Piecewise linear spline:

From the comments, it sounds like you expect your conditional expectation function to be piecewise linear. You could fit a piecewise linear spline.

- Figure out your spline points
- Fit a linear function (or polynomial) to each section